# VBsscript (.vbs) code gets cleared/removed

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

At the top of most of my VBscripts (.vbs files) I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Dim objFSO, objFile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs", ForReading)
Execute objFile.ReadAll()
```

This code allows me to use another vbs file as a library. In this case `somefile.vbs` would be my library and have all my subs and functions defined that are called from the script the above code is called from (I call this the calling script).

This issue: Every once in a while, one of the scripts seems to delete the code in `Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs` (the library script read by the calling script).

I think this because if a `wscript.exe` is listed in my Task Manager Processes tab and I restore the `Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs` file from a backup location, almost immediately, when I open `Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs` again, there is no code in that file. But if I kill the `wscript.exe` process, the file is fine. I can't reproduce the behavior because it only occurs when our network has a hiccup of some kind (I think).

My first thought is that the `create` setting is wrong when I use this line:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs", ForReading)
```

But according to this link, the default `create` value should be false:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx

Note, coincidentally, I am also using `objFile` and `objFSO` variables in the file `somefile.vbs` for things that aren't related to what I am doing in the calling script. For example, the `objFile` in the `somefile.vbs` file has a completely different name and location and is created this way:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("z:\differentpath\differentname.vbs", ForAppending, True)
```

I am guessing this is the issue, but I don't understand it. **Can someone shed some light on this?** Is the `create` or `append` setting getting reset in the calling script?  How does that work?

Not knowing what else to do I have change the variable names in the `somefile.vbs` file to `oFSO, oFile` and in the calling script they are still `objFSO, objFile`. I also changed the line of code in the calling script to include `false` for the `create` setting like this:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs", ForReading,false)
```

Comment: A wsf file will allow `<script src=...` inclusions and `<object>` to import constants from a type library. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gstemp/2004/02/24/how-come-you-guys-dont-use-wsf-files/

Comment: @AlexK. - Thanks. I don't understand what you wrote and how it applies, but will read the link and maybe that will help.

Comment: [Windows Script Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File) have an actual import mechanism, a feature that plain VBScript does not provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going out on a limb (since you posted only partial code) I'm going to assume that you don't explicitly close your library script after reading, so your main script keeps the file open until it terminates. Either add a line `objFile.Close` after the `Execute` statement, or (better yet) change

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs", ForReading)
Execute objFile.ReadAll()
```

to

```
code = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs").ReadAll
Execute code
```

or just

```
Execute objFSO.OpenTextFile("Z:\somepath\somefile.vbs").ReadAll
```

so that the file is automatically closed after being read.

Comment: The last/3rd solution you provide doesn't leave the file open? Thanks!

Comment: Both the 2nd and 3rd snippet should automatically close the file after reading. The difference is just that the 2nd snippet puts the code from the file in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Learned from https://ss64.com/vb/execute.html

> Execute takes a group of statements and executes them in local scope, ExecuteGlobal executes them in global scope.
>
> However, if the same Execute statement is invoked outside of a procedure (i.e., in global scope), not only does it inherit everything in global scope, but it can also be called from anywhere, since its context is global.

Does the issue remain if you call the Execute form a procedure?